# Using Outlook VBA to move MailItem Causing Run-Time Error 91; Object variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I'm attempting to have emails coming in to my main inbox (for testing, future second inbox) be routed to a subfolder. I want it to activate on all items on receipt. However, on the last line of the VBA code, `Item.Move olnamespace.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Subfolder")` fails with a run-time error 91. I'm not sure why and have attempted to troubleshoot it. VBA - let alone outlook side - is very new to me.

```
Private WithEvents secondinboxitems As Outlook.Items

Sub initializesecondinboxitems()
Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olnamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim secondinboxfolder As Outlook.Folder

'initialize outlook application and namespace
Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set olnamespace = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'specify the folder containing the emails in the second inbox
Set secondinboxfolder = olnamespace.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox")

'get the items collection for the second inbox folder
Set secondinboxitems = secondinboxfolder.Items

End Sub

Private Sub secondinboxitems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
'code to process the items

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olnamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim keyword As String

'set the keywords to search for.

keyword = "Keyword"

'check if the received item is a mail item

If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
'read email body as plain text
Dim body As String
body = Item.body

'check if keyword is present
If InStr(1, body, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

'Dim itemtomove As Outlook.MailItem
'Set itemtomove = Item

Item.Move olnamespace.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Subfolder")

End If
End If



End Sub
```

Is what I am working with. I tried assigning the item as a mail item more specifically. And, I tried re-setting `GetNamespace("MAPI")`. I assumed neither would be an issue. And i guess confirmed that when it didn't solve the problem. Any pointers on why the sub is failing on item.move would be appreciated.

Also! It seems to be reading the emails for the keyword base on a `debug.print` of the text compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: Your comment

tried;

```
Set targetFolder = olapp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Item.Move targetFolder
```

Which, once again has the error.

---

`olapp` does not exist in `Private Sub secondinboxitems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)`.

Try this cleaned up code to decrease the confusion.

```vb
Private WithEvents secondinboxitems As Items

'You could instead repeat the
' Set secondInboxFolder = Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox")
'in
' Private Sub secondInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim secondInboxFolder As Folder    

Sub initializeSecondInboxItems()

'specify the folder containing the emails in the second inbox
Set secondInboxFolder = Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox")

'get the items collection for the second inbox folder
Set secondInboxItems = secondInboxFolder.Items

End Sub


Private Sub secondInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

'code to process the items
Dim destFolder As Folder
Dim keyword As String

'set the keywords to search for.
keyword = "Keyword"

'check if the received item is a mail item
If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then

    'read email body as plain text
    Dim body As String
    body = Item.body
    
    'check if keyword is present
    If InStr(1, body, keyword, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' secondInboxFolder is declared at the module level
        Set destFolder = secondInboxFolder.Folders("Subfolder")
        Item.Move destFolder
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the error is thrown not by `MailItem.Move`, but by the code that retrieves the target folder. Try to break that line into two ti check if yo uare really failing to retrieve the target folder

```vb
set targetFolder = Item.Session.Folders("My Name").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Subfolder")
Item.Move targetFolder
```

If you are dealing with the a subfolder of the default Inbox folder, use GetDefaultFolder:

```vb
set targetFolder = Item.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Subfolder")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Dmitry Streblechenko. So, I checked both options plus 1. 
with 'set targetfolder', the same error 91 occured. This time on the 'set targetfolder' line. I attempted it again using the 'set targetFolder = olapp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Subfolder")' and the same occured. I thought it was possible it was the folder path and so i backed out of the subfolder and simply tried; 'Set targetFolder = olapp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Item.Move targetFolder'. Which, once again has the error.

Comment: As @niton noted, `olapp` and `olnamespace` are not initialized in the sub. Either make them global, or use `MailItem.Application` or  `MailItem.Session` property (see updated code above)